# If statement always returns false when consulting file

Tags: java, android, android-file

I'm importing files from the phone's storage to an Sqlite database.

To do that I need to type the file name that I want to import, but even if the file does not exist, the import method is still executed and the toast "No Such File" does not appear.

**Here's the code**

```
File new_ConsumerData = new File(String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()));

String data = new_ConsumerData.toString() + "/" + ToImportConsumerFileName + ".dat";

if (!new_ConsumerData.exists())
{
   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
   @Override
       public void run() {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Such File", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }
else
{
   \\importMethod
}
```

Comment: Use your debugger.

Comment: In your code example, the file will always exists, it is the de facto configured root directory of a storage mount. You have to create a file with both new_ConsumerData (root directory) and the "data" (file name).

Comment: A file can also refer to a directory, and as amanin says, in this case that's what you are taking as file.

Comment: fixed it!.. thanks guys.. be safe:)